# Predicate Calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

(a) All students who like computer science like mathematics.(S(x), C(x), M(x))

(b) There are some students who like Socrates but do not like Aristotle.
(S(x), L(x, y), S, A)

(c) No student who likes computer science also likes Oscar. (O, S(x), C(x), L(x, y))

We are supposed to use the predicate symbols provided. This was our first lecture on this topic so I am fairly new to predicate Calculus. For (a), I think I am correct with my result: ∀x ((S(x) ^ C(x)) -> M(x))

But for (b) and (c) I have absolutely no clue how to implement the symbols L(x, y) into the final result. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: **Hint** : "There are some students who like Socrates" is $\exists x(S(x) \land L(x,S))$.

Comment: So would this be syntactically correct?
∃x(S(x)∧L(x,S)∧L(x,¬A)

Comment: @SamSterling: No, since $A$ is not a logical statement (it is a non-logical constant) and therefore cannot be negated. You would negate $L(x,A)$ instead. See my answer for one correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a)\qquad \forall x([S(x) \land C(x)]\implies M(x))$$

$$(b)\qquad \exists x(S(x) \land L(x,S) \land \lnot L(x,A))$$

$$(c)\qquad \lnot \exists x(S(x) \land C(x) \land L(x,O))$$

or perhaps

$$(c)\qquad \forall x([S(x) \land C(x)] \implies \lnot L(x,O))$$

So your answer to (a) was correct, even if not correctly typeset.

Comment: I just came across these two practice questions that were meant for a challenge. How would you come across figuring these out? What is the method of thinking involved because I'm just sitting here and staring at them hopelessly till now. 

Each student who attended the meeting was accompanied by at least
one of his/her parents. (S(x), M(x), A(x, y), P(x, y))

Students are the only people who attended the meeting accompanied by one of their parents. (S(x), M(x), A(x, y), P(x,y))